# LWJGL The method getX() is undefined for the type Display

Tags: lwjgl

I would like to get the position of my window to be able to locate it in the same position as before after restarting my program.
The problem i ran into is that org.lwjgl.opengl.Display has no getX() and getY() methods.
Is there any way to get the position without these methods or do i need to get another lwjgl version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Display` does have static methods to get its position. See [here](http://lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/Display.html#getX())

So writing

```
int xpos = Display.getX();
```

will get you the needed value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems i had an old or corrupted version of lwjgl.